# Creating multiple deb packages using CPack

Tags: deb, packaging, debian, cmake

I have a project with several components and I am creating 4 DEB packages using CPack version 2.8.12. I have no issues with package generation as well as installation but these:

1. I am unable to make one package depend on another
2. By default, other files like `control.tar.gz` are getting installed in root directory, the files that I want to install are correctly getting installed under `/usr/lib`

I am unable to find a solution through the documentation.

Following is what CPack puts in my package:

```
$ dpkg -c opae-0.13.0-1.x86_64-libs.deb
-rw-rw-r-- root/root       432 2018-03-20 17:50 ./control.tar.gz
drwxrwxr-x root/root         0 2018-03-20 17:50 ./usr/
drwxrwxr-x root/root         0 2018-03-20 17:50 ./usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2018-03-20 17:50 ./usr/lib/libopae-c.so.0 -> libopae-c.so.0.13.0
lrwxrwxrwx root/root         0 2018-03-20 17:50 ./usr/lib/libopae-c.so -> libopae-c.so.0
-rw-r--r-- root/root    716702 2018-03-20 16:54 ./usr/lib/libopae-c.so.0.13.0
-rw-rw-r-- root/root       174 2018-03-20 17:50 ./md5sums
-rw-rw-r-- root/root        49 2018-03-20 17:50 ./prerm
-rw-rw-r-- root/root    122880 2018-03-20 17:50 ./data.tar.gz
-rw-rw-r-- root/root       192 2018-03-20 17:50 ./control
-rw-rw-r-- root/root         4 2018-03-20 17:50 ./debian-binary
-rw-rw-r-- root/root        85 2018-03-20 17:50 ./postinst
```

Comment: A.  »»unable to make one package depend on another 2)«« ... B. »»control.tar.gz are getting installed in root directory«« : Bugs in 'CPack' ? ... ``control.tar.gz´´ is not supposed to be installed anywhere. ... ... Dependency solution : Repack with `$ dpkg-deb -b` → i.e. add the "dependency" to the file `control` ( section "Depends:" )

Comment: Thanks for the information. dpkg-deb will let me add the dependencies, but I am looking for a solution to do that via CPack. you are right control.tar.gz should not get installed anywhere. Please take a look at my edit. I have added the contents of my package.

Comment: Please explain why you are using a buggy tool ? ... And : Can you stop " CPack" and do edits to `control` ? I.e. to add the missing dependency.